# Reshape a dataset with Start and End Dates to create a Time Series counting aggregate sum by day/month/quarter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset exactly like this:

```
ProjectID   Start   End Type
Project 1   01/01/2019  27/04/2019  HR
Project 2   15/01/2019  11/11/2019  Marketing
Project 3   25/02/2019  30/07/2019  Finance
Project 4   22/02/2019  15/04/2019  HR
Project 5   05/03/2019  29/09/2019  HR
Project 6   11/04/2019  01/12/2019  Marketing
Project 7   29/07/2019  23/08/2019  Finance
Project 8   25/08/2019  23/12/2019  Operations
Project 9   31/10/2019  29/11/2019  Operations
Project 10  10/12/2019  25/12/2019  Operations
```

I want to know over time, how many projects are outstanding by creating a daily/monthly/quarterly time series. I first want to create a sum of overall projects but then also know how many are outstanding by project type. From doing this manually in excel, I believe I have to resample the data somehow but i'm not sure how and on what dimensions... When I do this in excel, the output should in the end look like this:

[image]

and

[image]

[image]

how do I reshape the data with pandas to allow for this analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to take a date range (for example for 1 year) and then join all projects to all days. I'm using [hvplot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/) to create a nice interactive plot of the end result.

**Here's a working example with your sample data:**

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

text = """
ProjectID   Start   End Type
Project1   01/01/2019  27/04/2019  HR
Project2   15/01/2019  11/11/2019  Marketing
Project3   25/02/2019  30/07/2019  Finance
Project4   22/02/2019  15/04/2019  HR
Project5   05/03/2019  29/09/2019  HR
Project6   11/04/2019  01/12/2019  Marketing
Project7   29/07/2019  23/08/2019  Finance
Project8   25/08/2019  23/12/2019  Operations
Project9   31/10/2019  29/11/2019  Operations
Project10  10/12/2019  25/12/2019  Operations
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), header=0, sep='\s+')
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True)
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True)

# create a dummy key with which we can join all projects with all dates
df['key'] = 'key'

# create a daterange so that we can count all open projects for all days
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods=365, freq='d'), columns=['date'])
# create a dummy key with which we can join all projects with all dates
df2['key'] = 'key'

# join all dates with all projects on dummy key = cartesian product
df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['key'])

# check if date is within project dates
df3['count_projects'] = df3['date'].ge(df3['Start']) & df3['date'].le(df3['End'])

# group per day: count all open projects
group_overall = df3.groupby(
    'date', as_index=False)['count_projects'].sum()

# group per day per department: count all projects 
group_per_department = df3.groupby(
    ['date', 'Type'], as_index=False)['count_projects'].sum()

# plot overall result
plot_overall = group_overall.hvplot.line(
    x='date', y='count_projects',
    title='Open projects Overall',
    width=1000,
)

# plot per department
plot_per_department = group_per_department.hvplot.line(
    x='date', y='count_projects', 
    by='Type',
    title='Open projects per Department',
    width=1000,
)

# show both plots using hvplot
(plot_overall + plot_per_department).cols(1)
```

**Resulting plot:**

[image: plot with count of all projects using hvplot]

Comment: Astounded by the elegance and beauty of this solution as opposed to trying various melt and groupby solutions... I'm experimenting but can I confirm that getting quarterly, monthly etc would involve changing:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods=365, freq='d'), columns=['date'])

to df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods=12, freq='m'), columns=['date']) etc?

Comment: yeah, you change it like that, but do realize that if you change it to months, you just get 12 dates from the end of each month and then counts the number of open projects at that end of the month date